# Symfony2 fail during installation

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use Symfony2 with a local wamp server. I used

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

I moved the symfony file to `C:\wamp\www\test`.

And

```
php symfony
php symfony new myProject
```

But this message appear

```
Warning: include(phar://C:/wamp/www/Symfony/symfony/vendor/symfony/process/Symfo
ny/Component/Process/ProcessUtils.php): failed to open stream: phar error: Canno
t open phar archive "C:/wamp/www/Symfony/symfony" for reading in phar://C:/wamp/
www/Symfony/symfony/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412
```

The line 412 is

```
function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file;
}
```

Why did I have an error during the installation ? I did not perform any other actions except following the instructions on the official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use composer?The composer make more than "symfony" command file.